# MySQL LIMIT on multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, limit

Given the category name, I'm able to select the number of entries needed.
For example - `SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category = Taxi LIMIT 1, 2`.
This perfectly gives me 2 entries of Category = 'Taxi'.

Now, given an array of Category names, I need to perform a similar sql query, where I'll be able to fetch the required number of entries of each category.

**Requirement - I need to fetch all the data of 2 (LIMIT 1, 2) rows of each of categories in ['Taxi', 'Groceries', 'Delivery',  . . . . . . . . . . . ]**, using a single SQL query. Is it possible? If yes, please answer.

I tried this - `SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category IN ('Taxi', 'Groceries', 'Delivery',  . . . . . . . . . . . ) LIMIT 1, 2`, but it gave the same result as above.

This is how the products table looks like -

```
+----------+----------+------+
| Category | Items    | Count|
+----------+----------+------+
| Taxi     | Sedan    | 32   |
| Delivery | Food     | 34   |
| Delivery | Package  | 42   |
| Meals    | Sandwitch| 29   |
| Groceries| Butter   | 36   |
| Taxi     | SUV      | 39   |
| Groceries| Milk     | 39   |
+----------+----------+------+
```

Expected O/P -

```
+----------+----------+------+
| Category | Items    | Count|
+----------+----------+------+
| Taxi     | Sedan    | 32   |
| Delivery | Food     | 34   |
| Delivery | Package  | 42   |
| Groceries| Butter   | 36   |
| Taxi     | SUV      | 39   |
| Groceries| Milk     | 39   |
+----------+----------+------+
```

Rows order doesn't matter.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve that would be a UNION that combines the results of several individual SELECT statements.

Comment: @CBroe, but wouldn't that make it a bad query? In cases of like, 100 elements in Category array, the UNION will slow the process down considerably.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here in the end? You used the word “pagination” here, but so far I can not see it having much to do with that. Pagination does not even make much sense, unless you specify an order first.

Comment: @CBroe, I would like to fetch the data related the given list of categories. But not all of them. Every time I want the result to be some number of rows of each category, the number of rows is specified by LIMIT.

Comment: Well, again - unless you specify an ORDER, this makes little sense to begin with, because without the order is _random_. And depending on the complexity and amount of data it might perhaps make more sense to select all the data first, and then use the processing script logic to implement this form of “pagination” ...

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: Can you please add the expected O/P?

Comment: @Luke101 Added the desired O/P.

Answer (score 1):

Without `window functions` this will get real ugly. MySql does not currently support window function but MariaDb does. Why not convert to MariaDb which will make something like this so much easier. It is a drop in replacement for MySql as long as you're not using Json features or something. Most major companies like google and wikipedia have already made the jump. I would check it out. here is a sample query you can do:

```
SELECT category, item, itemcount as count FROM
(
     SELECT category,
          item,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY item) AS row_number,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, item ORDER BY item) as itemcount
     FROM products p
) a
WHERE a.row_number < 3
```

This query (untested) in mariadb will accomplish your requirement.

Comment: Great work. I have just test with MariaDB It's working well

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
SELECT p.category, p.items, p.count(*) num 
FROM product AS p 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product AS p2 
       WHERE p2.category = p.category AND p2.items >= p.items) <= 2 
ORDER BY p.category ASC, p.items DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is not standard SQL, you can't check that subquery returns result <=2

Answer (score 0):

group_concat might be your friend. Try that : it will display all items associated to a category, most frequent items should appear first

```
select category, group_concat(items) from 
FROM product 
group by p.category;
```

or

```
select category, group_concat(items) from 
(SELECT p.category, p.items, p.count(*) as nb 
FROM product AS p 
group by p.category, p.items) as viewcats;
```

limited to first 2 items :

```
select category, SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(items),',',2) from FROM product group by p.category;
```

Comment: But none of you queries will restrict the output to 2 rows only.

Comment: you can remove content after the second comma returned by group_concat

Comment: select category, SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(items),',',2) from 
FROM product 
group by p.category;

Comment: I think you didn't get his question correctly. He needs first 2 rows per category, not the result grouped by 2 results only.

Comment: group_concat is nobody's friend.

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that any failure in what follows to properly address the specifics of the question is merely a reflection of the inherent paucity of the question itself...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(Category VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,Items    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Count INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Taxi','Sedan',32),
('Delivery' ,'Food'     ,34),
('Delivery' ,'Package'  ,42),
('Meals'    ,'Sandwitch',29),
('Groceries','Butter'   ,36),
('Taxi'     ,'SUV'      ,39),
('Groceries','Milk'     ,39);

SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE category IN ('taxi','groceries','delivery');
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Category  | Items   | Count |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Taxi      | Sedan   |    32 |
| Delivery  | Food    |    34 |
| Delivery  | Package |    42 |
| Groceries | Butter  |    36 |
| Taxi      | SUV     |    39 |
| Groceries | Milk    |    39 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

For more targeted help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)